# No comment syntax defined

Tags: org-babel

After calling `org-babel-tangle` on a certain file containing latex
blocks, I see the prompt

> No comment syntax defined. Use:

What is this about?  This doesn't happen with another similar file I have.

PS.  Minimal example (which I couldn't easily provide before seeing the answer):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC latek :tangle yes :comments link
test
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's hard to tell what's the cause of your problem without an example that causes the problem you've described.

Comment: Please provide a recipe to reproduce what you see, starting from `emacs -Q`. It's not clear what you or Emacs did - the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means some code somewhere within the execution of `org-babel-tangle` wants to do something that depends on the syntax of comments (which depends on the language being used) and for some reason Emacs hasn't gotten that info (which is usually provided by the major mode).

You can try and track it down by typing `M-: (debug t) RET` from within the above prompt which should show you the nesting of function calls which finally lead to the prompt.

Comment: it says i'm attempting to use the minibuffer while in the minibuffer

Comment: Then try `M-: (setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t) RET` before reproducing the problem.

Comment: thanks!  this led me to find a `#+BEGIN_SRC latek` line, correcting which solved the problem

Comment: @Toothrot: You might want to report this as a bug to the Org guys: you shouldn't need to do this kind of low-level debugging to catch this kind of typo.